# randomize before creating folds using caret::createFolds?

Tags: r, cross-validation, caret

Do I need to shuffle my dataset first if it does not appear randomly ordered before creating folds with `createFolds` in the `caret` package? And how could I check it myself? (look into source code or else, since I didn't find relevant info in the manual?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It randomly samples folds while trying to balance the outcome variable `y` between  folds.

See [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/caret.pdf), page 28:

> For other data splitting, the random sampling is done within the
>   levels of y when y is a factor in an attempt to balance the class
>   distributions within the splits.